# Continuesly reading values for BLE in Android

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to interact with BLE  from the Android device and read some sensor values, I am following the API level > 21. I managed to scan the device and connect to it. First challenge was to read all the characteristic value together in one shot, some suggested to use priority queue to do that, I implemented like wise and it is working fine.

```
BluetoothGattCallback gattCallBack = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        switch (newState) {
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                Log.d(TAG, "STATE_CONNECTED");
                bluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
                break;
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                Log.d(TAG, "STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "STATE_OTHER");

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        final List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
        characteristics = new ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>();
        characteristics.add(services.get(1).getCharacteristics().get(0));
        characteristics.add(services.get(1).getCharacteristics().get(1));
        characteristics.add(services.get(1).getCharacteristics().get(2));

        characteristics.add(services.get(2).getCharacteristics().get(0));
        characteristics.add(services.get(2).getCharacteristics().get(1));
        characteristics.add(services.get(2).getCharacteristics().get(2));

        characteristics.add(services.get(3).getCharacteristics().get(0));
        characteristics.add(services.get(3).getCharacteristics().get(1));
        characteristics.add(services.get(3).getCharacteristics().get(2));
        requesReadCharacteristics(gatt);
    }

    public void requesReadCharacteristics(BluetoothGatt gatt) {
        gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristics.get(characteristics.size() - 1));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        if (status == 0 ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DeviceNameFetchFromDevice: " + characteristic.getValue());
            characteristics.remove(characteristics.get(characteristics.size() - 1));

            if (characteristics.size() > 0) {
                requesReadCharacteristics(gatt);
            } else {
                gatt.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
    }
};
```

Now I need to continuously monitor by BLE device to read the sensor value(like every interval of 10 sec), so I need to read the characteristic values repeatedly and get their values. But the ble won't allow to call "readCharacteristic" after first call.

For now I have implemented it like, calling connectDevice(BluetoothDevice) on regular interval, which is like disconnecting the exiting connection to BLE device and connecting it again. Is there any way where we can call readCharacteristic repeatedly being connected to the device. Disconnecting and connecting the device is not that efficient according to my understanding. Please let me know, what is correct approach to read device continuesly or share if there are any example like this

https://github.com/sandeeptengale/androidble/

Comment: Is there an error or what do you mean by "ble won't allow to call readCharacterisitc after first call"?

Answer (score 1):

first,you should turn on notification:

```
mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
```

then,you can read values in this method,when data changed:

```
onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)
```

Comment: Thank you @zkywaklker, but it will notify whenever characteristic values gets changed. I need to read each characteristic periodically without being disconnected

Comment: Did you get solution on how to read each characteristic periodically?

Comment: The notification period is up to the peripheral device. If you are also implementing the peripheral device, you can make it send the notification whenever you want. There is no protocol defined behaviour for the peripheral devices that make them send notifications only when the data changed.